# Firebase with google authentication -> project doesn't show image and credentials

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with firebase auth. I set up a firebase app following this tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#5

I've setup a `signInWithRedirect(provider);`
It's a quickstart btw. I setup a profilePicUrl and userName to show in index.html

```
var profilePicUrl = user.photoURL;   // TODO(DEVELOPER): Get profile pic.
var userName = user.displayName;        // TODO(DEVELOPER): Get user's name.

// Set the user's profile pic and name.

this.userPic.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + profilePicUrl + ')';
this.userName.textContent = userName;
```

I am unable to see those values. See GIF embded 
[image: noValues.gif]

Comment: it should look like this after https://ibb.co/ckioGQ

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: I have solved that. The problem was, i was logged in in console as a different user. Which has not enabled database. So i wrote "firebase logout" in cmd.